# grouping with right function sql

Tags: sql, group-by, count, trim

I have a query on grouping which I need to do a quick fix on. I am at present grouping column A and counting the value in column B.

```
select 
    Column A,
    Count ([Column B])
from table1
Group by Column A
```

The issue is that column A has some entries which are not standard for example.

```
ABC   100
ABC~  3
BCA   120
BCA*  4
```

I need to blast the data to fix long term, but there are 3m rows, so not a quick job, as I need to create a mapping file to deal with the problem. 
I currently get returned duplicate entries which is right in theory, but in practice I would like to group the ABC, by either trimming the column to only 3 characters or doing a right. However I have tried it in the select statement and it just removes the ~ or * entry and sums the standard ABC or BCA.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, to avoid incompatible answers suited for other products.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something ???

```
select LEFT([Column A], 3),
Count ([Column B])
from table1
Group by LEFT([Column A], 3)
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh, That did work, however I should have included the fact I have a join on a table which brings back the description for ABC, so I know need to see how the description could be picked up to show the same description for the left,3 on ABC~ as ABC. Does that make sense. Otherwise I will have a none match. Is it possible to join on just the first 3 char in a join?

Comment: @HAS can u add some more data & desire result ?